# Value of type "isActive" has no properties in common with type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>. React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm trying to pass isActive parameter inside NavLink of react-router-dom version 5, however, I'm getting two error.

*Value of type '({ isActive }: { isActive: any; }) => { color: string; background: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'. Did you mean to call it?*

*Binding element 'isActive' implicitly has an 'any' type.*

Code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Box, Breadcrumbs, } from '@mui/material';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

function handleClick(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

export const AppBreadcrumbs = () => {
  return (
    <Box
      role="presentation"
      onClick={handleClick}
      sx={{
        display: { xs: "none", sm: "none", md: "flex" },
        width: "100%",
        justifyContent: "center",
        padding: "1rem 0",
        boxShadow: 4,
      }}
    >
      <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb" separator="-">
        <NavLink
          to="/categorias"
          style={({ isActive }) =>
            isActive
              ? {
                color: '#000',
                fontWeight: "bold"
              }
              : { color: '#000'}
          }
        >
          Page1
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          to="/emprestimo"
        >
          Page2
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/doacao-de-livros">
          Doação de livros
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/favoritos">
          Page2
        </NavLink>
      </Breadcrumbs>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I tried to pass any as the type of 'isActive', but it still got an error.

```
  <NavLink
          to="/categorias"
          style={({ isActive:any }) =>
            isActive
              ? {
                color: '#000',
                fontWeight: "bold"
              }
              : { color: '#000'}
          }
        >
          Page1
        </NavLink>
```

Ps: The NavLink definition looks like this:

```
 export interface NavLinkProps<S = H.LocationState> extends LinkProps<S> {
     activeClassName?: string;
     activeStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
     exact?: boolean;
     strict?: boolean;
     isActive?<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string }>(match: match<Params> | null, location: H.Location<S>): boolean;
     location?: H.Location<S>;
}
```

Comment: You can't pass a function to the `style` prop.

Comment: Just get rid of the lambda wrapper `style={isActive ? a : b}`. It looks as if you are possibly copy/pasting code from the internet without understanding what it does. If so that isn't going to get you too far.

Comment: @caTS That's just flat out incorrect. You can pass just about anything you want as a *value* to a React component's props. Now, whether or not the *value* is valid is a different story. That is what declaring [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) or using Typescript is for.

Comment: Where did you get that `NavLinkProps` definition? That interface is missing the `style` prop. What specific version of `react-router-dom` have you installed as a dependency? Note that all pre-v6 versions of `react-router`/`react-router-dom` weren't written in Typescript, so any TS definitions are external to the package.

Comment: For reference, here is the ***current*** RRDv5 (5.3.3) [`NavLinkProps`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts#L77-L90) interface.

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom@5` the `NavLink` component's `style` prop function callback is passed a single argument that ***is*** the `isActive` value.

See [NavLink::style](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/style-object-func)

> `style` can either be a `React.CSSProperties` object or a function
> that returns a style object. If the function `style` is used, the
> link’s `active` state is passed as a parameter.
>
> ```
> <NavLink
>   to="/faq"
>   style={isActive => ({
>     color: isActive ? "green" : "blue"
>   })}
> >
>   FAQs
> </NavLink>
> ```

Your code:

```
<NavLink
  to="/categorias"
  style={(isActive) => isActive
    ? { color: '#000', fontWeight: "bold" }
    : { color: '#000'}
  }
>
  Page1
</NavLink>
```

If you need to type it, it's a boolean type:

```
style={(isActive: boolean) => isActive
  ? { color: '#000', fontWeight: "bold" }
  : { color: '#000'}
}
```

Note that in `react-router-dom@6` the `NavLink` component API *did* change significantly, not unlike many other RRDv6 components.

RRDv6 [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link)

> ```
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     LinkProps,
>     "className" | "style" | "children"
>   > {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => string | undefined);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

It seems you might've been referencing an incorrect version of the docs.

Comment: I added the boolean type and the error continues. I opened the NavLink file and this appeared:

export interface NavLinkProps<S = H.LocationState> extends LinkProps<S> {
     activeClassName?: string;
     activeStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
     isActive?<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string }>(match: match<Params> | null, location: H.Location<S>): boolean;
}

Comment: @Paula I don't believe there should be anything you need to type at all. I'm thinking you might be overcomplicating things. Could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: resolved problem, thank you

Comment: @Paula Resolved by an answer here, or by some other means?

Comment: It was by other means

Comment: @Paula I'm curious what the issue actually was. Do you mind posting as an answer what/how you resolved your specific issue? It may be helpful to others. I was also starting to wonder if you were using a *much* older version of `react-router-dom` and that's why the props are different than what I was expecting/assuming, so can you also clarify the specific *installed* versions of dependencies?